# Find and replace text in metadata of feature classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, batch, metadata

I have 36 feature classes in individual feature datasets.  I need to update a portion of the metadata for all the feature classes.

I want to find a string of text in the distribution portion of the metadata and replace it with a new string of text.

What would be the best way to do so? Do I have to manually update all 36 feature classes?

Can you write a python script to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to export all metadata using [ExportMetadata_conversion](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Export_Metadata/00120000000t000000/),
and then manipulate (find and replace the text) the exported XMLs and then reimport them using [ImportMetadata_conversion](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Import_Metadata/00120000000w000000/)

Comment: Agree with @Farid Cher, and you can script the export/import and edition of the XMLs with python if you are planning to edit metadata regularly or for more than a single field. If this is a one-off, you'll be faster with a batch export, search and replace in all opened documents (if in notepad++), and a batch reimport.